# existence of partial derivatives and differentiability of a 2-dimensional function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continous function  with $f(0,1)=2$ and let $g(x,y)=xf(x,y)$.

I've got to check out if $\frac{\partial g}{\partial  x}(0,1)$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial  y}(0,1)$ exist. Then I've got to check if  g is differentiable at $(0,1)$.

Well, my calculations are, as $g(0,1)=0*f(0,1)=0*2=0$:

$\frac{\partial g}{\partial  x}(0,1)=\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{g(0+t,1)-g(0,1)}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{tf(t,1)-0*2}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0}f(t,1)=2$

$\frac{\partial g}{\partial  y}(0,1)=\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{g(0,1+t)-g(0,1)}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{0-0*2}{t}=0$

I hope these calculations are fine. In the first equation I'm not sure if the condition of continuity of f at (0,1) is enough to confirm that. As the two partial derivatives exist, for differentiabiliy I've got to check:
$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,1)} \frac{g(x,y)-g(0,1)-\nabla g(0,1)(x-0,y-1)}{||(x,y)-(0,1)||}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,1)}\frac{xf(x,y)-0-2x-0(y-1)y}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}}=0$, which would mean that $g$ is differentiable at $(0,1)$. But here I am  not convinced of my solution. Anyone can check or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes to your first question. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(t,1)\to f(0,1)=2$ as $t\to 0$. As for differentiability, I would justify it a little bit more. Write it as
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}}(f(x,y)-2)$$ and use the fact that
$$\left\vert \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}}\right\vert\le 1,$$
while $f(x,y)-2\to 0$ as $(x,y)\to (0,1)$ by continuity.